# Defining and using a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I'm in the process of learning Python, and I have some code that isn't doing what I thought it should do.  I'm using v3.4.3.  Most likely the problem is this:

```
class Router:
    '''A representation of a router'''
    name = ''
    ifc = []

class Interface:
    ifName = ''
    addr = []
    helpers = ''

    def __init__(self,routername,num):
        self.ifc = []
        self.name = routername
        for i in range(num):
           self.ifc.append(Router.Interface())
```

My intent it to create a router  object that has a variable number of interfaces.  This number is known when I attempt to create the router via

```
d=[]
d.append(Router('r0',2))
```

which creates a Router d, with name='r0', and with two interfaces.  This part works great.

The next thing I'm attempting to do involves the individual interfaces on the router object.

An interface can have a variable number of IP addresses assigned to it, starting at 0, and I think the upper limit is probably 16, but that isn't really important.  Most of my interfaces will have between 1 and 6 IP addresses assigned to it, and I do not know the exact number when I create the router object, and this number can also change over time, as can the actual IP addresses involved.

I've written a bit of code to demonstrate what is going on and what I expected to happen.  Each time I call the prnt function, I expect it to print out the up to two IPs for one interface on one router, a la:

Desired Output for R0, Interface 0.  Others should be similar.

```
Router:  0 Interface:  0 Name:  Vlan100
         0 ('1.1.1.0', '1.1.1.1', '255.255.255.0', 'secondary')
Router:  0 Interface:  0 Name:  Vlan100
         1 ('2.2.2.0', '2.2.2.1', '255.255.255.0', '')
```

What actually appears to be happening is that the IP data for a specific router interface is not being applied to the interface, but being applied to the Router Class.

Code:

```
def prnt(rtr, ifnum,label):
'''debug routine for showing results'''
    print('\n',label,len(d), len(d[rtr].ifc),len(d[rtr].ifc[ifnum].addr))
    for j in range(len(d[rtr].ifc[ifnum].addr)):
        print('Router: ',rtr,'Interface: ',ifnum,'Name: ',d[rtr].ifc[ifnum].ifName,'\n\t\t',j,d[rtr].ifc[ifnum].addr[j])
    print('\n')
    return

#Define 8 IP networks.

net1 = ('1.1.1.0', '1.1.1.1', '255.255.255.0', 'secondary')
net2 = ('2.2.2.0', '2.2.2.1', '255.255.255.0', '')
net3 = ('3.3.3.0', '3.3.3.1', '255.255.255.0', 'secondary')
net4 = ('4.4.4.0', '4.4.4.1', '255.255.255.0', '')
net5 = ('5.5.5.0', '5.5.5.1', '255.255.255.0', 'secondary')
net6 = ('6.6.6.0', '6.6.6.1', '255.255.255.0', '')
net7 = ('7.7.7.0', '7.7.7.1', '255.255.255.0', 'secondary')
net8 = ('8.8.8.0', '8.8.8.1', '255.255.255.0', '')

# create d, a blank list
d=[]
print('Define list d.  Length of d:',len(d))

#make d an object r0 of the Router class.  Router has two interfaces.
d.append(Router('r0',2))
print ('Append r0. Length of d:',len(d),'Interface count:',len(d[0].ifc))

#make d an object r1 of the Router class. Router has two interfaces.
d.append(Router('r1',2))
print ('Append r1. Length of d:',len(d),'Interface count:','r0:',len(d[0].ifc),'r1:',len(d[1].ifc))

#Name four interfaces, two on each router
d[0].ifc[0].ifName='Vlan100'
d[0].ifc[1].ifName='Vlan101'
d[1].ifc[0].ifName='Vlan200'
d[1].ifc[1].ifName='Vlan201'
print ('Name Interfaces. Length of d:',len(d),'Interface count:',
       'r0:',len(d[0].ifc),'r1:',len(d[1].ifc))

# show the router interface information.  At this point, nothing should print, as
# none of the interfaces have IP addresses attched to them
prnt(0,0,'I expect nothing #1')
prnt(0,1,'I expect nothing #2')
prnt(1,0,'I expect nothing #3')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #4')

#
#The intent is to populate two IP addresses onto each of the four interfaces
#Starting with R0-0, I'll add one IP at a time and print each of the four interfaces
d[0].ifc[0].addr.append(net1)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1 only on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect nothing #5')
prnt(1,0,'I expect nothing #6')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #7')
#
d[0].ifc[0].addr.append(net2)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1 and 2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect nothing #8')
prnt(1,0,'I expect nothing #9')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #10')
#     
d[0].ifc[1].addr.append(net3)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1 and 2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect nothing #11')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #12')
#     
d[0].ifc[1].addr.append(net4)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1 and 2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3 and 4.4 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect nothing #11')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #12')
#
d[1].ifc[0].addr.append(net5)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1/2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3/4.4 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect 5.5 only on r1 ifc 0')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #13')
#
d[1].ifc[0].addr.append(net6)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1/2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3/4.4 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect 5.5/6.6 on r1 ifc 0')
prnt(1,1,'I expect nothing #14')
#
d[1].ifc[1].addr.append(net7)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1/2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3/4.4 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect 5.5/6.6 on r1 ifc 0')
prnt(1,1,'I expect 7.7 only on r1 ifc 1')
#
d[1].ifc[1].addr.append(net8)
prnt(0,0,'I expect 1.1/2.2 on r0 ifc 0')
prnt(0,1,'I expect 3.3/4.4 on r0 ifc 1')
prnt(1,0,'I expect 5.5/6.6 on r1 ifc 0')
prnt(1,1,'I expect 7.7/8.8 on r1 ifc 1')
```

I had somebody tell me that embedding a class within a class is an issue, so I'm attempting another approach, something along the lines of:

```
 class Address:
    '''representation of the data required for a valid interface
    type is either '' (primary) or 'secondary' '''
    sub=''
    gw=''
    mask=''
    typ=''

class Interface:
    '''representation of an interface'''
    ifName = ''
    addr = []
    helpers=''
    def __init__(self,name,ipnum):
        self.ifName = name
        self.addr = [Address(i) for i in range(ipnum)]

class Router:
    ''' representation of a router'''
    name = ''
    ifc = []
    def __init__(self,name,ifnum):
        self.name = name
        self.ifc =[Interface(i) for i in range(ifnum)]
```

Is this a step in the right direction?  I'm a bit hung up on the order (and steps) in which I would create the various objects.  For a given router, can I create the router object first, followed by the interfaces, followed by the addresses, or do I need to do it in the opposite order?  I have a lot of IP space distributed around over 100 routers to get a handle on.  Please forgive my lack of precision with OOP terminology.  I'm old school, learning new stuff.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to ask here. Are your class performing correctly? Are you asking about style/coding advice or how to solve a problem you're having?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is way to broad for a usual Stack Overflow question. To help you on improving your post I'll suggest getting familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make sure that when you create a new class instance, you pass the right parameters (number and type) its `__init__` expects.  E.g. Interface.__init__ needs two params, but you only send it one.  And Address doesn't even have a `__init__` method, but you send it `i`.

Comment: It's confusing when you use `d` as a global variable.  You should make it meaningful (all caps) and define it above your prnt function.

Comment: To me, the general direction looks right.  You may want to add a method to `Interface` to retrieve one of them by name.